# add .js file on react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

in old version i use javascipt to communicate with a local installed software and get image from a scanner.
the js file has multiple function and variables to show or hidden  and communicate with local soft using ws://...

i try to integrate with react like this :

```
  <HelmetProvider>
  <Helmet>
    <head>{`
    <script src="http://localhost/scan.js" type="text/javascript" />
    `}</head>
   
  </Helmet>
  <main role="main">
        <div className="py-5 bg-light">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row" id="th_container">
              <div className="col-md-12 mb-1 text-secondary" id="th_container_empty">no photo</div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12">
              <Button
                name='btn-scan'
                id='btn-scan'
                variant="flat"
                color="primary"
              >
                <Trans message="Launch scanning" />
              </Button>
               
                <div className="text-danger mt-1" id="download-app" style={{display: 'none' }}>
                  no apps installed!          
                  <a href="exescan/setup.exe"><button  className="btn btn-success">Download Software For scan</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
```

that not work, any ideas,

Comment: `style={{display: 'none' }}` ?

Comment: need to be removed and controle it with javascipt 

 : document.getElementById("download-app"),

Comment: try adding script as dom item instead of string
<head><script src="http://localhost/scan.js" type="text/javascript" /></head>

Comment: @PrathapParameswar return : 


`browser.js:38 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Helmet expects a string as a child of <head>. Did you forget to wrap your children in braces? ( <head>{``}</head> )`

Comment: try with react-helmet need to remove `<React.StrictMode>` that run a simple alert("test");